# How can I hide sections in Wordpress (header and footer) based on url?

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I have wordpress website and I want any page that is accesed with /no_header to be shown without header and footer, basically to hide those two sections. I'm new to php/wp and I don't know how to tackle the problem.

Example:

1. testsite.com/about -> shown normal like  it is
2. testsite.com/about/no_header -> shown without header and footer, only the content.

Edit: I mention that I have Elementor Pro and WPRocket installed, if that helps or it's relevent in a way.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Elementor, you shouldn't need to go to the code.
For all of its downsides, this type of flexibility is one of its perks.

In the pages where you don't want header and footer, look for the Page Attributes on the right sidebar, as shown here:

https://www.josevarghese.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Elementor-Canvas-for-Hiding-Header-and-Footer.png

Elementor Canvas should hide the header and footer on the pages where it is selected as the Template.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your answer, but that doesn't help me. The idea is that I need some sort of function that hides header and footer when it's being called, like in the example I've written. I want every page to have header and footer but only when I call link_to_page/no_header to hide the header and footer.

Comment: @Damian I want to help you but I don't understand how what you need is different from what I proposed in the answer, where you hide the header and footer on any page, like on link_to_page/no_header

Comment: I appreciate your take, maybe I wasn't explaining clear enough, my english is not that good. The idea is that I don't want some pages without header and footer, I want all to have them. But, when I enter on a page and I add "/no_header" at the end of the URL, I want it to show them without header and footer. It's a function, not a subpage or anything else.

Comment: Ahhh now I get it, thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

I would find some selectors that identify the header and footer (like an id, or a class that is used a single time) and would write some CSS file that would have `display: none;` for them. When the page is loaded with no header/footer, then I would load that CSS file into the `head` tag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did that, I assigned a class with to those two sections. But I don't know how to make the /no_header at the end of the url part. It's crucial to be that way because that's how the client wants it. I have an idea where I can make, like you said, a class with display: none and somehow add it with a function which detects that there is a /no_header in the URL, but I don't know how.

Comment: @Damian with `home_url( $wp->request )` you can get your current URL. With `strpos($someurl, 'no_header') !== false` you can find out whether $someurl contains 'no_header'.

Comment: Should I use it with wp_enqueue_style and add_action  ?